# Get previous day's date from date passed as a string in "YYYY-MM-DD" format

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a helper function `getPreviousDay` to be used in the backend (`Flask`).

From the front end, I'm receiving the `date` in `"YYYY-MM-DD"` format as a string.
From this, I want to get the date of the previous day in the same format as a string.

Here's a sample code of what I want to achieve.

```
def getPreviousDay(date):
    '''
    todo: previousDay should also be a string in "YYYY-MM-DD" format
    '''
    return previousDay
    

current_day = "2022-09-29" #YYYY-MM-DD
yesterday = getPreviousDay(current_day)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime` module provides `date` and `timedelta` types that can be used for this kind of thing. A "time delta" is a difference between two dates or times, in this case, 1 day. Subtracting one day from today's date gives yesterday's date.

```
import datetime


def getPreviousDay(date):
    today = datetime.date.fromisoformat(date)
    yesterday = today - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return yesterday.isoformat()
```

This returns:

```
>>> getPreviousDay('2022-09-29')
'2022-09-28'
```

The reference documentation for the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) has more details.